# Why does this syntax work to parse an associative array value into a string?

Tags: php

I'm going through the PHP lessons at codeacademy.com and lesson 4/7 of Advanced Arrays wants an `echo` statement written that accesses values from an associative array.

My first attempt was:

```
echo "I own a $myAssocArray['colour'] $myAssocArray['doors']-door $myAssocArray['year'] $myAssocArray['make'].";
```

which throws the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on line 26

I realize I can do this with the concatenation operator:

```
echo "I own a " . $myAssocArray['colour'] . " " . $myAssocArray['doors'] . "-door " . $myAssocArray['year'] . " " . $myAssocArray['make'] . ".";
```

While playing around, I got this to work simply by removing the apostrophes in the array accessor. The below compiles with no errors and produces the expected string:

```
echo "I own a $myAssocArray[colour] $myAssocArray[doors]-door $myAssocArray[year] $myAssocArray[make].";
```

I can also use the curly brace notation to access the array value the way I think I need to:

```
echo "I own a {$myAssocArray['colour']} {$myAssocArray['doors']}-door {$myAssocArray['year']} {$myAssocArray['make']}.";
```

My understanding is that associative array values are accessed either by index (integer) or key (string).

1. Is my understanding incorrect?
2. Or is there some underlying principle that I'm not grasping?
3. Or is this a behavior specific to the PHP compiler used by codeacademy.com?

How is this syntax able to be accurately parsed?

```
echo "some text $associative_array[key] some more text";
```

How does the compiler know to interpret `key` (or `colour`, `doors`, `make`, `year`, etc.) as a string value?

Comment: It's how php designed: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-93

Comment: 1. Your understanding is correct. 2. No. 3. It's behaviour that PHP just has. Weird, right? 4. See 3

Comment: Also as a rule if you are doing that then most people prefer that curly brace notation is used. Though most sane people would probably use `printf|sprintf` or `strtr`...

Comment: People migrating from C would use `printf` at least, but if you move from C to PHP, I'm not sure if the term 'sane' applies to you. ;)

Comment: Ha... well not if you want to get into web development. There are obviously other langs out there that many might consider better or at least with a more acceptable list of shortcomings than PHP, but once you get used to it its not bad. There are however, a lot of poorly disciplined developers out there using it haha which i feel is partly why it gets such a bum rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how PHP is, where consistency is a mortal sin:

- Array keys in a double-quoted string can NOT be quoted, unless they're within the `{}` embedded syntax.
- Multi-dimensional arrays/objects in a double-quoted string are parsed in a non-greedy manner, which is why there's the `{}` extended string syntax.

Consider:

```
$foo['bar']['baz'] = 'qux'; // a simple 2 layer array
```

The obvious one:

```
echo "Hello, $foo['bar']['baz']" // error: t_encapsed_and_whitespace
```

Quick hack fix, remove the quotes:

```
echo "Hello, $foo[bar][baz]" // outputs: Hello, Array[baz]
```

which is actually parsed/executed as:

```
echo "Hello, ";    // plain string
echo $foo['bar'];  // array in string context, which will print as the word "Array"
echo "[baz]";      // Another plain string
```

Since PHP's parser isn't greedy, it stops after the FIRST `]`, thinking that that's the end of the array. So your "upper" array gets converted to a string, resulting in the literal word `Array`, and the rest of the array key business is just treated as plain text.

Enter the extended syntax:

```
echo "Hello, {$foo['bar']['baz']}"; // Outputs: Hello, qux
```

The `{}` serve to delimit the ENTIRE array/object reference, forcing PHP to treat all of the `[]` blocks as keys. And since you're now in a special "array-/object-in-string" mode, the array keys must be quoted again.

For objects, the same thing occurs:

```
$foo->bar->baz = 'qux'; 
echo "Hello, $foo->bar->baz";
```

which then results in a "object of stdclass could not be converted to string", because it was parsed/executed as:

```
echo "Hello, ";
echo $foo->bar;
echo "->baz";
```

Unless the `bar` sub-object implements the magic `__toString()` method, then the "could not be converted" error occurs. But regardless, putting in the `{}` notation makes it work"

```
echo "Hello, {$foo->bar->baz}"; // outputs: Hello, qux
```